# Remove loop calculating a non-continous temporal averaging feature in Python 3

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a for loop doing something I would have thought relatively straight forward on Python 3

```
# input_array is a time series of 1 minute data from x number of sites (cols), it is not necessarily continuous, though each timestep is unique. 
IN[1]: input_array
Out[1]: 
array([[0.14013903, 0.32521612, 0.11172546, ..., 0.37796091, 0.39655287, 0.09020338],
       [0.13153962, 0.34140063, 0.11812597, ..., 0.35862739, 0.4282353 , 0.08757173],
       [0.12921372, 0.35564918, 0.11834597, ..., 0.35499742, 0.4506885 , 0.0851089 ],
       ...,
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,        nan,        nan],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,        nan,        nan],
       [       nan,        nan,        nan, ...,        nan,        nan,        nan]])


# time_5m is the 5min timestamps that i desire an average of:

In[2]: time_5m
Out[2]: 
0    2020-04-01 09:42:30
1    2020-04-01 09:47:30
2    2020-04-01 09:52:30
3    2020-04-01 09:57:30
4    2020-04-01 10:02:30
       
95   2020-04-01 17:37:30
96   2020-04-01 17:42:30
97   2020-04-01 17:47:30
98   2020-04-01 17:52:30
99   2020-04-01 17:57:30
Length: 100, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In[3]: type(time_5m)
Out[3]: pandas.core.series.Series


# time_1m is the 1min timestamps corresponding to the input_array
In[4]: time_1m
Out[4]: 
3638583   2020-04-01 09:41:00
3638584   2020-04-01 09:42:00
3638585   2020-04-01 09:43:00
3638586   2020-04-01 09:44:00
3638587   2020-04-01 09:45:00
       
3639078   2020-04-01 17:56:00
3639079   2020-04-01 17:57:00
3639080   2020-04-01 17:58:00
3639081   2020-04-01 17:59:00
3639082   2020-04-01 18:00:00
Name: Tm, Length: 500, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

What I currently do is loop each output desired timestamp, find all minutes within that range, and take the average. However, this is wildly inefficient for large time series

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

# pre allocate the output array
output_array = np.full((5, time_5m.shape[1]), np.nan)

for i, t in enumerate(time_5m):
  # calculate the mean of the corresponding 1-min
  inds = np.logical_and( time_1m > t - timedelta(minutes=5/2), time_1m < t + timedelta(minutes=5/2) )
  if sum(inds)>1:
    output_array[i, :] = np.nanmean(input_array[inds, :], axis=0)
```

I would really appreciate some advice how to remove this issue.

Every solution I usually use depends on the data being continuous and complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can't use `pd.DataFrame.resample('5 min').mean()` out-of-the-box because `time_5m` isn't at 'normal' positions past the hour (i.e. `time_5m` is at `2:30, 7:30, ..., 57:30` past the hour.)  That is, `time_5m` is 2.5 minutes offset from the 'normal' positions past the hour (where the 'normal' positions are at `0, 5, 10, ..., 55` minutes past the hour).

Pandas version 1.1 introduced two new keyword arguments for `resample()`: `origin` and `offset` ([here are the docs for DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html))

So something like this should work:

```py
import pandas as pd
input_df = pd.DataFrame(input_array, index=time_1m)
resampled = input_df.resample('5 min', offset='2.5 min').mean()
```